# Contactless smart card authentication as Signature Terminal (ST) during PACE fails

Tags: nfc, digital-signature, smartcard, apdu, contactless-smartcard

I am trying to access `eSign` application of the smart card. If I understood correctly for that I first need to authenticate as Signature Terminal (ST) during PACE. (Because currently if I try to select `eSign` application I get file not found.)

This is the APDU I am sending during `MSESetAT` to achieve that:

```
0x00 - instruction class
0x22 - instruction code
0xC1 - p1
0xA4 - p2
0x20 - length

0x80 - oid tag
0x0A - oid length
0x04, 0x00, 0x7F, 0x00, 0x07, 0x02, 0x02, 0x04, 0x02, 0x04 - PACE oid

0x83, 0x01, 0x02 - CAN password id

0x7F, 0x4C - Certificate Holder Authorization Template
0x0E - length
0x06 - oid tag
0x09 - oid length
0x04, 0x00, 0x7F, 0x00, 0x07, 0x03, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03 - id-ST oid (0.4.0.127.0.7.3.1.2.3)
0x53 - tag for data
0x01 - length of data
0x03 - 2 lowest bits set for generating qualified electronic signature, and electronic signature
0x00 - expected response length
```

The response I get is `sw1 - 0x6A`, `sw2 - 0x80` which corresponds to: `Incorrect parameters in the data field`.

However, if I swap the `id-ST` oid with `id-AT oid`: `0x04, 0x00, 0x7F, 0x00, 0x07, 0x03, 0x01, 0x02, 0x02`, it succeeds and I get `sw1 - 0x90, sw2 - 0x00`

Am I forgetting something or is it maybe not even possible to achieve over NFC?

The smart card I am trying with is a national ID card of Croatia, and I am following `TR-03110` specifications.

Comment: If you really got 0x6180, the meaning is, that the card has an answer part of 128 bytes (and possibly more) for you. Your text would correspond to 0x6A80.

Comment: You are right, I am getting 0x6A80. I made a typo, I will edit the question.

Comment: You first need to read EF.CardAccess. SW=6A80 means something wrong with data itself (NFC is fine). I might only guess: protocol algorithm isn't supported , or terminal type indicated by CHAT is not authorized to use PACE, or you missed e.g. tag 65.

Comment: I didn't mention here, but I already read EF.CardAccess so I could get PACE info. If PACE isn't supported by signature terminal, how else am i supposed to verify it? And what do you mean by tag 65, what should I put with that?